# Closing C# socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a button with the following code:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(entered_ip);

    foreach (var address in host.AddressList)
    {
        var ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, 7779);
        var samp = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        samp.Connect(ipe);

        if (samp.Connected)
        {
            enable_anticheat();

            Process.Start("samp://" + entered_ip + ":" + entered_port);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to close the socket `samp` when the app closes. But how can it be closed?
I understand that the socket is closed by calling `samp.Close()`, but if I add this in the `FormClosing` event for the form, I get the error `element does not exist in the current context`.

The code I am trying to use is:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    samp.Close();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your variable socket should be declared outside the function as a member of your class.

Comment: I know, but how to? Help please :(

Answer (score 1):

There you go, although I should mention that you probably don't want to keep clicking on the button or it'll open various sockets all of the same connection or at the very least throw an error.:

```
private List<Socket> samp = new List<Socket>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
        //If you don't want the error
        //if(samp.Count > 0) return;
        IPHostEntry host = null;
        Socket sock;
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(entered_ip);

        foreach (IPAddress address in host.AddressList)
        {

            IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, 7779);
            sock = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            sock.Connect(ipe);

            if (sock.Connected)
            {
                enable_anticheat();
                samp.Add(sock);
                Process.Start("samp://" + entered_ip + ":" + entered_port);
                break;
            } //The else continue is unnecessary. 
        }
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(samp.Count > 0) {
      foreach(Socket s in samp) {
         s.close();             
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Woops just was programming in java. It should be `foreach(Socket s in samp) {`